# clone syscall and mutual exclusion

Tags: c, clone, system-calls

I'm trying to practice with clone syscall and a little example of an incrementing counter shared by 2 threads. Code is as follows:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sched.h>

#include "error.h"

/*------------------------- Mutual exclusion ------------------------------*/

void EnterCZ()

{
   if (sched_setscheduler(getpid(), SCHED_FIFO, &(struct sched_param) { .sched_priority = 1 }) == -1)
      SysError("EntrarZC:sched_setscheduler");
}

void ExitCZ()
{
   if (sched_setscheduler(getpid(), SCHED_OTHER, &(struct sched_param) { .sched_priority = 0 }) == -1)
      SysError("SalirZC:sched_setscheduler");
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define STACK_SIZE 65536
#define N 100000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int n = 0;
   char *stack;

   int Child(void *args) {
      int i, temp;

      for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
         EnterCZ();
         temp = n;
         temp++;
         n = temp;
         ExitCZ();
      }
      return 0;
   }

   printf("initial n = %d\n", n);

   if ((stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE)) == NULL)
      RTError("main:malloc");
   if (clone(Child, stack + STACK_SIZE, SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_VM, NULL) == -1)
      SysError("main:clone");
   if ((stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE)) == NULL)
      RTError("main:malloc");
   if (clone(Child, stack + STACK_SIZE, SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_VM, NULL) == -1)
      SysError("main:clone");

   while (wait(NULL) != -1) ;

   printf("final n = %d\n", n);

   return 0;
}
```

execution result is:

```
initial n = 0
final n = 199999
```

should be 200000, so mutual exclusion by means of raising priority fails, why?

Answer (score 1):

There are several things wrong here:

- Several SCHED_FIFO processes can run simultaneously on several CPUs.
- SCHED_FIFO processes may/will be killed if they exceed the RLIMIT_RTTIME soft/hard limit.
- There's nothing preventing reordering of instructions by the compiler.
- There's nothing preventing reordering of instructions by the CPU.

Comment: do you come up with a code modification that would execute successfully? Thanks

Comment: The first one cannot be solved cleanly if you have several CPUs/cores. For the third and fourth you need to use appropiate barriers (barriers prevent reordering of memory accesses).

Answer (score 0):

According to the man page for clone(), the stack should point to the last address in allocated memory. Your reference of "stack + STACK_SIZE" is actually beyond the allocated memory.

Comment: stack argument is indeed correct, just take a look to Linus' example: http://tldp.org/FAQ/Threads-FAQ/clone.c

Comment: Sorry JayG, I didn't take void * args into account, but replacing stack + STACK_SIZE by ((void *)(stack + STACK_SIZE))-1 doesn't help. Last execution was:

`final n = 199996`

Answer (score 0):

The `clone()` syscall (particularly the `CLONE_VM` flag) is not intended for direct use by application programmers creating threads.  It is a low-level interface, intended for library authors creating full threading implementations.  Similarly, sychronisation primitives for these threads can be built on top of the low-level `futex()` system call, but again this is not intended for direct use by application programmers.

Instead, you should be using pthreads.  Under pthreads, use `pthread_create()` instead of `clone()`; `pthread_join()` instead of `wait()`; and `pthread_mutex_lock()` / `pthread_mutex_unlock()` to protect critical sections.  The pthreads version of your program would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#include "error.h"

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#define N 100000

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int n = 0;
   pthread_mutex_t n_lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
   pthread_t child1, child2;

   void *Child(void *args) {
      int i, temp;

      for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
         pthread_mutex_lock(&n_lock);
         temp = n;
         temp++;
         n = temp;
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&n_lock);
      }
      return 0;
   }

   printf("initial n = %d\n", n);

   if (pthread_create(&child1, NULL, Child, NULL) != 0)
      SysError("main:pthread_create");
   if (pthread_create(&child2, NULL, Child, NULL) != 0)
      SysError("main:pthread_create");

   pthread_join(child1, NULL);
   pthread_join(child2, NULL);

   printf("final n = %d\n", n);

   return 0;
}
```

Compile with the `-pthread` flag to gcc.

Comment: Yes, I already knew this. My pthreads example, like yours, works flawlessly. But I was trying to practice with the low level interface for this example

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks to everybody for pointers, insights and ideas, I always learn from you.
As an academic exercise, I was trying to guarantee mutual exclusion by rising priorities, which, obviously, only works for uniprocessors.

As ninjalj pointed out the code doesn't work if "Several SCHED_FIFO processes can run simultaneously on several CPUs"

The solution to make this code work is simply to run executable on only one CPU:

...$ taskset -c 0 puerta-clone

works well, regards

Comment: You haven't still fixed the rest of the problems. The fact that it works now is an artifact of your compiler and your CPU.

Comment: Of course, but at least it serves as an academic exercise, which was my purpose in the first place

Comment: The easy (and recommended) way of doing this is using mutexes. If you really want to pursue this, C1X (latest draft as of writing is n1548.pdf) has a section on multi-threaded execution and data races (5.1.2.4) and a couple chapters on <stdatomic.h> and <threads.h> (7.17 and 7.25). And of course, Paul E. McKenney has a great book on parallel programming titled "Is parallel programming hard? And if so, what can you do about it?"